# How to find Bundles containing specific item (component/page)

Tags: core-service, bundles

I am trying to find a list of bundles that contain a spcific component/page, I could not find a sample code, I searched the core services API doc, I found `ContainingBundlesListInfo` but I don't know how to use it.

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

please stop using WhereUsed for everything, it's quite heavy list and it affects performance a lot. There's a special filter to show bundles that contain the current item: `ContainingBundlesFilterData`.

```
string componentId = "tcm:5-4081";

CoreServiceClient channel = new CoreServiceClient();

ContainingBundlesFilterData filter = new ContainingBundlesFilterData();

var bundles = channel.GetList(componentId, filter);
```

There are also many nice properties on that filter.

Answer (score 6):

This source code, will give you the list of bundles

```
string componentId = "tcm:5-4081";

CoreServiceClient channel = new CoreServiceClient();

UsingItemsFilterData filter = new UsingItemsFilterData();
filter.ItemTypes = new ItemType[] { ItemType.VirtualFolder };

XElement xBundles = channel.GetListXml(componentId, filter);
```

Answer (score 3):

I imagine you will find it with a UsingItems  filter